# Can I get a Stream of results from "as" when using Anrom in the Play! Framework?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, scala-collections, anorm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an easy way to get a Stream as output of a RowParser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270825/is-there-an-easy-way-to-get-a-stream-as-output-of-a-rowparser)

When I have a statement like this when using Anorm in the Play! Framework:

```
def all(): List[Note] = 
    DB.withConnection { implicit c => SQL("select * from note").as(note *) }
```

it appears to return a List of my model objects.  Can I do this differently so I can get a Stream[Note] instead so it does "lazy" loading of the rows?  Or maybe it is already somehow even though it claims to be returning a List.

In other words, if I do all().head I would want it to only have fetched the first row.  It appears to me that before the "as" it starts out as a stream, but after "as" it is a List.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270825/is-there-an-easy-way-to-get-a-stream-as-output-of-a-rowparser) yesterday, so you might want to check that out. I gave a solution to your problem, but my question was about having a more elegant/concise way to achieve the same.

If you generate a `List`, there is nothing lazy about it, your whole result is parsed and returned. However, even if you use a `Stream`, for performance reasons, you should try to reduce the number of rows already in your query. For example, if you are only interested in the first n rows, you should add `limit n`, otherwise the database will still be queried for all rows, and you will just save a little time by not parsing them when using `Stream` instead of `List`.

Answer (score -1):

Check this link http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaAnorm

You can use the `apply()` method instead of the `as()` to get the Stream but then you will have to parse the Note yourself.